# A non-Borel union of unit half-open squares

Tags: gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, plane-geometry

On the complex plane $\mathbb C$ consider the half-open square $$\square=\{z\in\mathbb C:0\le\Re(z)<1,\;0\le\Im(z)<1\}.$$

Observe that for every $z\in \mathbb C$ and $p\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ the set $(z+i^p\cdot\square)$ is the shifted and rotated square $\square$ with a vertex at $z$.

> **Problem.** Is it true that for any function $p:\mathbb C\to\{0,1,2,3\}$ there a subset $Z\subset\mathbb C$ such that the union of the squares
>   $$\bigcup_{z\in Z}(z+i^{p(z)}\cdot\square)$$is not Borel in $\mathbb C$?

---

**Added in Edit.** As @YCor observed in his comment, the answer to this problem is affirmative under $\neg CH$.

An affirmative answer to Problem would follow from an affirmative answer to another intriguing

> **Problem'.** Is it true that for any partition $\mathbb C=A\cup B$ either $A$ contains an uncountable strictly increasing function or $B$ contains an uncountable strictly decreasing function?

Here by a *function* I understand a subset $f\subset \mathbb C$ such that for any $x\in\mathbb R$ the set $f(x)=\{y\in\mathbb R:x+iy\in f\}$ contains at most one element.

---

**Added in the Next Edit.** In the discussion with @YCor we came to the conclusion that under CH the answer to both problems is negative. Therefore, both problems are independent of ZFC. Very strange.

Comment: It's even "a non-Borel union of unit squares".

Comment: In view of my answer, I'm wondering if you wanted for $Z$ to be Borel.

Comment: @NateEldredge it should be very easy to adapt your construction if $Z$ is assumed to be Borel but not $p$.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks, shall I add this into my answer?  (Oh, you deleted your comment, is there a problem with it?)

Comment: Yes, although it addresses the question in the same way I interpreted it (for some $p$ instead of for any $p$). Anyway I think your answer should better be undeleted.

Comment: If for some line $L$ of negative slope we have $p^{-1}(\{0,2\})\cap L$ uncountable, then it contains a non-Borel subset and Nate's argument adapts. Idem if for some line $L$ of positive slope we have $p^{-1}(\{1,3\})\cap L$ uncountable. If none applies (for lines of slope $\pm 1$), CH holds, so already we're done in the negation of CH.

Comment: But under CH I'd be surprised if there would exist a subset of the plane meeting every affine line of negative slope into a countable subset and with complement meeting every affine line of positive slope into a countable subset.

Comment: @YCor Just consider (the graph) of a well-order of the real line. Under CH it intersect each vertical line is a countable set and each horisontal line in a cocountable set.

Comment: @TarasBanakh yes I know but it's not what I asked; I'm asking much more.

Comment: @YCor Thank you for the great idea with CH. I had a feeling that this question is of set-theoretic nature but thought about something more serious than CH, like PFA.

Comment: @YCor In fact, instead of lines one can take monotone (partial) function, where we have a lot of freedom. But under CH there exist two uncountable subsets $X,Y\subset\mathbb R$ such that there is no strictly increasing function $f:dom(f)\to Y$ defined on an uncountable subset $dom(f)\subset X$.

Comment: Indeed I've just noticed this too. Call negative curve a subset $C$ of the plane satisfying $(y-y')(x-x')<0$ for any two $(x,y)\neq (x',y')$ in $C$, and similarly positive curve. The question becomes whether there exists a subset of the plane meeting every negative curve in a countable set, and whose complement meets every positive curve in a countable set. How is the result you just quoted under CH related to this?

Comment: @YCor The result I quoted is weaker because $X$ and $Y$ can be very small uncountable sets. On the other hand, we require to have a partition of the whole plane, so the pieces cannot be small. But maybe we can choose such a partition by "killing" all monotone functions? The continuity argument shows that the number of such functions is continuum. So all of them can be "killed" under CH in $\omega_1$ steps.

Comment: @YCor Exactly: under CH we can construct such a partition by just counting all monotone continuous functions defined on $G_\delta$-sets and noticing that the intersection of an increasing and decreasing functions is finite. So, Problem' has negative solution under CH and so does the original Problem. Very good!

Comment: Once such a strange partition is given, and defining $p$, say valued in $\{0,1\}$ accordingly, is it clear that for every Borel subset the union $U_{Z,p}$, as you define, is Borel?

Comment: @YCor Yes, but it requires some (non-trivial) job. I am going to write a separate paper on this topic and hope that you could join to the project (as a generator of crucial ideas) -- of course after looking at the text.

Comment: @YCor Several minutes ago I sent you a paper (9 pages long) with all the proofs to your e-mail.

Answer (score 4):

(This addresses a misinterpretation of the question, where $p$ can be chosen.  I'll try to fix it.)

This seems too easy, so maybe I've misunderstood the question, but: let $L$ be the diagonal line $\{z : \Re(z) = - \Im(z)\}$ and let $Z$ be a non-Borel subset of $L$.  Take $p \equiv 0$.  Then the set in question is $E = \bigcup_{z \in Z} (z + \Box)$, but we have $E \cap L = Z$ so that $E$ is not Borel.

Comment: It is not that easy: note that we have the function $p$, which rotates the squares. It may happen that on this diagonal line $p(z)=1$ then the union of such squares will be the open strip.

Comment: Remark: assuming (as we can) that $Z$ is dense in $L$, then $E$ is equal to the open strip $\{x+iy:0<x+y<2\}$ union $Z$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I don't know if you're addressing Nate's answer or my comment, but in both we have $p=0$ as assumption.

Comment: @YCor The problem was to find a non-Borel union for ANY function $p$, not for SOME $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Both problems have negative answer under CH and positive answer under $\neg$CH. The proofs can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02243).