# Borel selections of usco maps on metrizable compacta

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

The problem posed below is motivated by [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/329935/61536) of Chris Heunen and in fact is its reformulation in the language of usco maps. Let us recal that an *usco map* is an upper semicontinuous compact-valued map.

> **Problem S.** Does each usco map $\Phi:M\multimap K$ from a compact metrizable space $M$ to a compact Hausdorff space $K$ admit a Borel selection?

Looking at the literature I found a lot of results addressing this problem. For example the classical [Kuratowski-Ryll-Nardzewski Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_and_Ryll-Nardzewski_measurable_selection_theorem) implies the affirmative answer to Problem S if $K$ is metrizable. 
By [Hansell, Jayne and Talagrand (1985)](https://eudml.org/doc/152762), the answer to Problem S is affirmative if $K$ is fragmenable. 
On the other hand, by [the result of Graf](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01507290) or [Cascales-Kadets-Rodrigues](https://www.um.es/beca/papers/MeasSelections.pdf), every usco map $\Phi:P\multimap K$ from a Polish space $P$ to a compact Hausdorff space $K$ has a universally measurable selection.

But to my surprise looking through the literature I cound not find an answer to Problem S (or I overlooked something?). All existing results imposing some restrictions on $K$ (like being fragmentable or linearly ordered) suggest that one should expect a counterexample. And indeed, there exists a [counterexample](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02243) under $\neg CH$:

> **Example.** There exists an usco map $\Phi:[0,1]^2\multimap K$ to some Hausdorff compact space $K$ (namely, the square of split interval), which has a Borel selection if and only if the Continuum Hypothesis holds.

But what about a ZFC-counterexample to Problem S? What is known in this respect?
Is the above Example known to specialists in the field?